# Linking two pages

Tags: javascript, php, authentication

I am working on trying to link pages together so if a person were to login using the login page, they would be redirected to a specific created page, and if a user clicked the register button, they would be redirected to the register page and from there, after inputting in information, they would be directed to another page.  The button for login or register does not work. Is there a way to fix this?

So far I have this for my login page.

```js
function login() {
  var users = ["admin1", "admin2", "admin3", "admin4"];
  var pass = ["pass1", "pass2", "pass3", "pass4"];

  ivar aUser = document.getElementById("user_name").value;
  var aPass = document.getElementById("password").value;

  for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i] == aUser && pass[i] == aPass) {
      window.location = "dashboard.php";
      break;
    }
  }

  var myOut = document.getElementById("output");
  myOut.innerHTML = "Who Are You? / Incorrect Password";
  myOut.className = "error";

  function init() {
    var login_button = document.getElementById("login_button");
    if (login_button !== null) {
      login_button.onclick = login;
    }

    var register_button = document.getElementById("register_button");
    if (register_button !== null) {
      register_button.onclick = validation;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      var myErr = document.getElementById("err" + i);
      if (myErr !== null) {
        myErr.className = "error";
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<h1>
  Please Login
</h1>
<form id="order_form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <div class="tab">
      <div class="tRow">
        <div class="tRow">
          <div class="tCell">
            <label for="user_name">User Name:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="tCell">
            <input type="text" id="user_name" maxlength="50" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END OF THIS SELECTION -->
        <div class="tRow&gt; &lt;div class=">
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="tCell">
          <input type="text" id="password" required="" maxlength="50" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END OF THIS SELECTION -->
      <div class="tRow">
        <div class="tCell">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="tCell">
          <input type="button" id="login_button" value="Login" />
        </div>

      </div>
      <!--END OF THIS SELECTION-->
      <div class="tRow">
        <div class="tCell">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="tCell">
          <input type="button" id="register_button" value="Register Now!" />
        </div>

      </div>
      <!--END OF THIS SELECTION-->
    </div>
    <!-- END OF THE TABLE  -->
    <br />
    <div id="output" class="error"></div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Validation function:

```
function validation() {

    for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
      var myErr = document.getElementById("err" + i); 
      myErr.innerHTML = "";
   }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";


        var dept_name = document.getElementById("dept_name").value;
        var user_email = document.getElementById("user_email").value;
        var user_password = document.getElementById("user_password").value;
        var phone_number = document.getElementById("phone_number").value;
        var first_name = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
        var last_name = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
        var office_location = document.getElementById("office_location").value;



        var valid = true;

        if (dept_name == "") {
            document.getElementById("err1").innerHTML = "Invalid!";
            valid = false;
        }

        if ((user_email) =="") {
        valid = false;
        document.getElementById("err2").innerHTML = "Invalid!"; 
        }

        if ((user_password) =="") {
        valid = false;
        document.getElementById("err3").innerHTML = "Invalid!"; 
        }

        if ((first_name) =="") {
        valid = false;
        document.getElementById("err4").innerHTML = "Invalid!"; 
        }

        if ((last_name) =="") {
        valid = false;
        document.getElementById("err5").innerHTML = "Invalid!"; 
        }

        if (isNaN(phone_number) || card_number.length !==11) {
        valid = false;
        document.getElementById("err6").innerHTML = "Invalid!"; 
        }

        if ((office_location) =="") {
        valid = false;
        document.getElementById("err7").innerHTML = "Invalid!"; 
        }
}
window.onload=init;
```

Comment: Why do you store passwords and usernames on a js file? I hope it's an internal project...

Comment: Send the userID and password to a PHP that makes the decision to save the login state in the session and send a redirect header

Comment: It is.  Pretty much it's a sample project

Comment: I created you a snippet. It immediately shows a spelling error and a missing bracket. Please fix that `ivar` ?

Comment: Also  `var userPos = users.indexOf(aUser); if (userPos !=-1 && userPos === pass.indexOf(aPass))  window.location = "dashboard.php";`

Comment: Alright. I didn't see the i there for a minute. So I pretty much place that within the js. file or where var is at?

Comment: It is not the most important. The missing brackets and not calling init will kill the script. As will the missing validation function

Answer (score 0):

Several errors

1. missing brackets
2. no execution of init
3. missing validation function

This works:

```js
function login() {
  var myOut = document.getElementById("output");

  var users = ["admin1", "admin2", "admin3", "admin4"];
  var pass = ["pass1", "pass2", "pass3", "pass4"];

  var aUser = document.getElementById("user_name").value;
  var aPass = document.getElementById("password").value;

  for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i] == aUser && pass[i] == aPass) {
      myOut.innerHTML = "Correct - you will be redirected";
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = "dashboard.php";
      },1000);  
      return;
    }
  }
  myOut.innerHTML = "Who Are You? / Incorrect Password";
  myOut.className = "error";
}


function init() {
  var login_button = document.getElementById("login_button");
  if (login_button !== null) {
    login_button.onclick = login;
  }

  var register_button = document.getElementById("register_button");
  if (register_button !== null) {
    register_button.onclick = validation;
  }

  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var myErr = document.getElementById("err" + i);
    if (myErr !== null) {
      myErr.className = "error";
    }
  }
}
function validation() { /* you need some code here */ }
window.onload=init;
```

```html
<h1>
  Please Login
</h1>
<form id="order_form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <div class="tab">
      <div class="tRow">
        <div class="tRow">
          <div class="tCell">
            <label for="user_name">User Name:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="tCell">
            <input type="text" id="user_name" maxlength="50" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END OF THIS SELECTION -->
        <div class="tRow&gt; &lt;div class=">
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="tCell">
          <input type="text" id="password" required="" maxlength="50" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END OF THIS SELECTION -->
      <div class="tRow">
        <div class="tCell">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="tCell">
          <input type="button" id="login_button" value="Login" />
        </div>

      </div>
      <!--END OF THIS SELECTION-->
      <div class="tRow">
        <div class="tCell">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="tCell">
          <input type="button" id="register_button" value="Register Now!" />
        </div>

      </div>
      <!--END OF THIS SELECTION-->
    </div>
    <!-- END OF THE TABLE  -->
    <br />
    <div id="output" class="error"></div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

You can make the test simpler:

```
var userPos = users.indexOf(aUser); 
if (userPos !=-1 && userPos === pass.indexOf(aPass)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This really helps out alot. I do have the bad habit of missing brackets and I need to work on that. I do have a validation function but the way I have it set up only applies to the registration.php

Comment: This is what I have for the validation function: Added it in original post.

Comment: Anyway. I fixed your buttons. Now you can continue. Feel free to delete the question since it is VERY localised to your situation